# Create folders and filters with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

With the following command with my user admin and role impersonation can access to my account:

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber
```

Once the connection is made, can I switch to another account?

I am trying to create folders and filters to execute the commands using New-MailboxFolder but doesn't work directly from my account. It's possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change current user. You will create another script to do what you want to do as another user. Then in your current script use this:

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $UserCredential -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "-noexit -command TheNewCreatedScriptFullPath.ps1"
```

Comment: Where should the remote user be defined?